# Оптимизация Mysql

Tags: php, оптимизация, mysql

Здравствуйте. Помогите мне пожалуйста решить вот такую проблему:
Человек просматривает новость (id новости передаётся через GET), мне нужно слазить в базу данных выбрать из одной таблицы текст этой новости, из второй таблицы комментарии к данной новости, и из третьей таблицы информацию о юзерах оставивших комментарии.

Как мне лучше поступить в плане оптимизации запросов. Следует ли делать для этого три различных запроса или например следует выбрать из одной таблицы текст новость, а дальше объеденить таблицу комментариев с таблицей данных о пользователе оставившем комментарий. Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: На ваш вопрос невозможно ответить до тех пор, пока у вас 0% принятых ответов.

Answer (score 1):

Хранение имен пользователей в таблице с комментами добавит лишь дополнительный гиморой, так что, по-моему, проще будет оставить все 3 таблицы и выбирать записи оттуда через join3 select.

А если уж и извращаться излишними оптимизациями, то стоит сделать отдельно поле comments(longtext) прямо в таблице с новостями, и в этом поле хранить все комменты, id пользователей и их ники в json-формате, например.

Answer (score 0):

Настолько поджимает, что стоило задуматься над оптимизацией? По мне так это стандартная модель вывода новостей с комментариями.

Всё зависит от того, какую информацию о пользователе вы выводите, если только имя, то в принципе можно в таблицу к комментариям добавить еще поле - имя пользователя, который добавил комментарий.

В итоге может получиться два простых запроса к базе данных. Один, который выводит новость, а второй - который выводит комментарии (по ID новости переданному через _GET) и имя пользователя и его ID, по которому можно пройти на профиль.

Comment: Нет, только именем тут необойтись. Обращаться к третьей таблице нужно будет полюбому.

Comment: Ну тогда один запрос к новостям, а второй комментарии с внутреннем обьединением к пользователям.